# aws network elb not generating logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elb

I am trying to configure access logs for AWS Network ELB following this doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-access-logs.html

I specified bucket name & prefix, then selected `Create this location for me`

Following bucket policy was auto generated for the bucket

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "AWSConsole-AccessLogs-Policy-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AWSConsoleStmt-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:root"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/prefix/AWSLogs/123456789012/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSLogDeliveryWrite",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name/prefix/AWSLogs/123456789012/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AWSLogDeliveryAclCheck",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "delivery.logs.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket_name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Bucket is created, but under `AWSLogs/xxxxxxxx` there aren't any log files generated. Anything I am missing here ?

Comment: Have you set the correct bucket policy? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-access-logs.html#access-logging-bucket-requirements

Comment: Updated my question

Comment: So it created the `AWSLogs` directory? That indicates that it has permission to write to the bucket. How often are you uploading logs? Did you wait long enough for logs to appear?

Comment: I waited 24 hr lastime, then deleted the bucket and recreated it. but same issue again.

Comment: Do you see the `ELBAccessLogTestFile` under your prefix?

Comment: Can you confirm that traffic is reaching your LB?

Comment: I don't see anything under `bucket_name/prefix/`.

Comment: Other services are access the service running on backend machines through this elb. So yes traffic is reaching to ELB.

Comment: Are you using a TLS listener?

From the documentation: Access logs are created only if the load balancer has a TLS listener and they contain information only about TLS requests.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue with the NLB. But, in my case, I am only listening for HTTP requests. I have correct policy set for my bucket which is being utilized by the ALBs as well and they are logging perfectly fine but in case of NLBs, I am getting this issue where the structure s3://bucket_name/prefix/nlb_name/AWSLogs/account_id/ has been created by NLB but there are no log files in this path!

Comment: i'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Did anyone get an answer to this?

Answer (score 10):

From : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-access-logs.html

> Access logs are created only if the load balancer has a TLS listener
>   and they contain information only about TLS requests.

Comment: jeez, hours wasted

Answer (score 0):

It could be one of the following three:

- Permissions Error: The **S3 Log Delivery** need access to the target
  bucket.
- Permissions Error: Bucket should be enabled to accept logs.
- Configuration Error: Amazon S3 object lock must not be enabled.
- Configuration Error: If enabling encryption, only AES256 is [supported](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html#access-logging-bucket-permissions).
- Access logs are created only if the load balancer has a TLS listener and they contain information only about TLS requests.
- Allow some time for recent logging configuration changes to take effect.

Further reading: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-server-access-log-not-delivered/